# How can I mimick the behavior of a UINavigationController with HTML inside a UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

In my iPhone app, I have a "Help" screen. Currently, I use an almost fullscreen UIWebView and display an RTF with the help text inside. But as the app is growing in terms of functionality, so is the online manual. I just have to split it up and subdivide it into several "pages".

Now I wonder whether it is possible to do so without any (or only little) change to the application code, i.e. whether it is possible to mimick the behavior of a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with HTML inside the existing UIWebView. The result should look roughly like the [iPhone user manual](http://help.apple.com/iphone/4/interface/) (switch the UserAgent to "Safari iOS 4.3.3" to see it). The HTML source however should be stored in local files on the device.

Is this possible? If so, does it require more or less effort than programming the same thing directly in Objective-C?

Ideally, I would like to have kind of a skeleton, where I only have to fill in my help text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)? It can give you a navigation controller kind of look with HTML 5. It meant for safari applications, but I think that it should also work within a UIWebView also.

Comment: Does it work offline i.e. without a server? It generally looks right, but I am looking for a more "lightweight" solution. I found that Apple's Safari sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/iPhoneListPatterns/Introduction/Intro.html is almost all that I need. (Only transitions are missing.)

Comment: @LPG I've never used it that way, but it should be either directly embeddable or available through a file:/// URL. BTW: have you seen [iOS CSS animations performance](http://albertogasparin.it/articles/2011/06/ios-css-animations-performances/) and [Fast animation with iOS WebKit](http://joehewitt.com/2011/10/05/fast-animation-with-ios-webkit)

Comment: Another possible solution that I have discovered myself would be http://www.iui-js.org/. However, just like jQueryMobile, this is a fairly complex framework. Since I am developing a native app anyway, using HTML for the online manual only makes sense, if doing so means reducing the overall complexity.

After all, I wonder whether it is easier to write a couple of extra navigation controllers in Objective-C. Note I am am way better with that than with HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Doing so would also avoid any potential issues with licenses.